# How to have python interact automatically with a web site

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web

Ok,  so I've looked around on how to do this and haven't really found an answer that showed me examples that I could work from.

What I'm trying to do is have a script that can do things like:
-Log into website
-Fill out forms or boxes etc.

Something simple that might help me in that I though of would be for example if I could write a script that would let me log into one if those text message websites like textnow or something like that,  and then fill out a text message and send it to myself.

If anyone knows a good place that explains how to do something like this,  or if anyone would be kind enough to give some guidance of their own then that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: selenium is what you're looking for: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Ok,  I will check out the link which you've provided.  I'm assuming the docs will be able to teach me what I need to know in order to do what I need to do.  In case I still have a more specific question I'll comment again and hopefully you'll be around to point me in the right direction again.  Thank you for the help.  On a side note,  I'm also starting to play a lot with c# and I've been wanting to do the same thing with it,  so if by any chance there would be anther quick answer for that which you now about then i'd appreciate that too.   Again,  thank you.

Comment: You can get selenium for c# as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some good answers and further research,  I have found that selenium is the thing that best suits my needs.  It works not only with python,  but supports other languages as well. If anyone else is looking for something that I had been when I asked the my question, a quick Google search for "selenium" should give them all the information they need about the tool that I found best for what I needed.